# Textured cube renders blank in DirectX

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, textures, directx-9

I am trying to apply textures to a cube in DirectX 9, so far I have made it to draw it with vertex colors and light as well as with a material and light, but now with the texture I get a blank cube, in my application it renders white, in PIX it renders black. I know the texture is loaded correctly as I can see it from PIX and as I have made sure I can detect any error the loading function may return (through the `HResult`) **Edit: it was the same image on a surface,** but with a breakpoint I see the texture has an address, and thus exists, whether it is right or not I cannot tell, should I be able to see it in PIX? I also know that I've got the UV's right as they appear right in PIX as I select the vertices, and they are indeed in clockwise order (at least one face is, but that should be enough to draw *something*).

I have removed the light code so the code is:

```
pd3dDevice->BeginScene();

setMatrices();

pd3dDevice->SetTexture(0, tex);
//pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_WRAP0, D3DWRAPCOORD_0);
pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);

//pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);

// select which vertex format we are using
pd3dDevice->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

// select the vertex buffer to display
pd3dDevice->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));

pd3dDevice->SetIndices(i_buffer);

// copy the vertex buffer to the back buffer
pd3dDevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST,
                                0,
                                0,
                                8,
                                0,
                                12);
pd3dDevice->EndScene();
```

`setMatrices()` does the transformations, it worked well before I added lights so it should be fine. I commented out the call to the light handling function, so it shouldn't meddle with the current code.
I notice that if I remove `pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);` I get a black unshaded but transformed cube, which to me seems reasonable.

The commented out lines of code, I have tried with and without them, they do not seem to effect the situation as far as I can see. I have tried a couple more render state settings but no luck - after all they were mostly educated guesses and not something that was supposed to work.

The FVF has XYZ, normal vector and UV.

Again, PIX shows the cube as black, I have it white in the application. Perhaps there's a hint there?

Thank you for any attempt to help out, much obliged.

Comment: Whats your exact FVF and vertex struct? Did you ensured that `D3DFVF_TEX1` is part of it? (When I started with FFP and textures I mistakenly used `D3DFVF_TEX0`) And finally the obligatory well-intentioned comment for DX9: It is veery old, if you don't really need to use it, try to start with DX11 and forget about the FFP ;)

Comment: `struct CUSTOMVERTEX {FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DVECTOR NORMAL; FLOAT U, V;};`

`#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL | D3DFVF_TEX1)`

Comment: FFP=?
I'd go for 11 all right, but I'm kinda stuck with some old machines since I don't study in my home town, so I'm working on XP to maintain humane performance - plus I get more access rights and so on - so 9 is the way to go for now. I also embrace the idea of backwards compatibility more than Microsoft does, though that's not that critical at the moment

Comment: FFP = Fixed Function Pipeline, this is the easy way of DX9 to render, without using VertexDeclarations, VertexShaders and PixelShaders. Thus it is only useful to do simple things and whilte advancing in the rendering topic it will be soon to limited to use further. As well as learning the concepts of shaders is usable for DX11, too. But some years ago, I started to learn DX with the FFP, too ;) Back to topic: did you set the texture transform `D3DTS_TEXTURE0`? I'm running out of ideas, maybe you could post your whole code to pastebin or so?

Comment: Ah yes, I do intend to dive into shader programming, but I think it's wise to start with the basics, I'm sure you agree :)
Could you write the line of code I need to call? The code I pasted is pretty much everything I changed from the previous, working version to this one, so I'm pretty sure I did no such thing... If that doesn't work I'll compress the project and paste a link

Comment: Ok, we have results! but still not exactly the right ones... I set `D3DTS_TEXTURE0`, I also had to add `pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_COUNT2);` to get it to apply that, only I am not at all sure which matrix to use. I do get some rough color on a corner or two but it's far from what it should be, considering each triangle covers half the image.

Comment: Cool! Could you post an screenshot? Or how does it differ from the expected result?

Comment: Ok, so it's transformed but it's as if I've placed the coordinates in completely wrong positions, I just need the right matrix now.. This is what I've got, the cube is the distorted surface above the 'e' in DirectX, the texture is the logo in the upper-right hand corner (I'm proud to have created a button out of it):
http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~vpapadatos/textureAppliedWrong.JPG

Comment: It comes down to finding a decent tutorial/guide to doing the right transforms finally, I got more of the image on when I did object*rotation*projection*lookAt, still not sure if it's my carelessness towards the coordinates (I'm stepping into meshes right after I'm done with this so I didn't bother much with being perfect) or if I haven't done something..

Comment: Note: The [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) for Direct3D 11 provides a number of 'canned' shaders to make it easier to 'start with the basics' without all the messiness of learning the legacy fixed-function pipeline of legacy Direct3D 9 just to ignore it all when you get going with shaders.

Comment: I'm sure upgrading to 11 will make stuff a lot cleaner, but as long as I don't have constant access to windows 7, I'll have to work with 9. But I also like low-level and legacy stuff, so this may be useful experience and I like it anyway.